# Count of rows by month within period

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm working on a T-SQL function to return the count of two categories (enrolls and verifies) for each month within a specific period. The function below works only when there is at least a count greater than 1 for each month. What I'd like to do is given a start date of the lowest date found in the source table, an end date of today, and a given number of months, return the counts of enrolls, and the count of verifies for a given user id between the start and end period of months.

Ideally I'd like the range-period data be formatted as `MMM-YYYY`. For any months during this period where there are no counts, I'd like those values to show a count of 0.

`RELEASED_DATETIME` is a `DATETIME` column in the `INTERACTION_SESSION_T` table.

Valid Data for a period of 7 Months

```
RANGEPERIOD | ENROLLS | VERIFIES
------------+---------+---------
Nov-2017    |    15   |    15
Dec-2017    |   150   |  2582
Jan-2018    |     0   |     0
Feb-2018    |     0   |    98
Mar-2018    |    10   |     0
Apr-2018    |     8   |     0
May-2018    |    12   |    85
```

My code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SVE_GET_ENROL_VERIFY_COUNT_MONTH_R]
     (@DEV_ID INT, @NUM_MONTHS INT)
RETURNS @D TABLE (RANGEPERIOD VARCHAR(10),
                  TOTAL_ENROLLMENTS INT,
                  TOTAL_VERIFICATIONS INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cur VARCHAR(12); -- stores the current record date the cursor points to
    DECLARE @sdate DATETIME;  -- start date of range
    DECLARE @edate DATETIME;  -- end date of range
    DECLARE @tot_enrls INT;   -- stores the @cur date's enrollment count
    DECLARE @tot_verfs INT;   -- stores the @cur date's verification count

    SELECT @sdate = MIN(RELEASED_DATETIME)
    FROM SVE_INTERACTION_SESSION_T 
    WHERE (DEVELOPER_OWNER_ID = @DEV_ID OR DEVELOPER_USER_ID = @DEV_ID) 
      AND RELEASED_DATETIME >= DATEADD(MONTH, -@NUM_MONTHS + 1, GETDATE())

    SELECT @edate = GETDATE();

    INSERT INTO @D (RANGEPERIOD)
        (SELECT
             RANGEPERIOD = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(datename(month, I.RELEASED_DATETIME), 1, 3 ), '-', YEAR(I.RELEASED_DATETIME))
         FROM
             SVE_INTERACTION_SESSION_T AS I WITH (NOLOCK) 
         INNER JOIN 
             SVE_APPLICATIONS_T AS A WITH (NOLOCK) ON I.APPLICATION_ID = A._ID
         WHERE
             (I.DEVELOPER_OWNER_ID = @DEV_ID OR I.DEVELOPER_USER_ID = @DEV_ID) 
             AND I.RELEASED_CODE = 'C' 
             AND A.IS_DELETED = 0 
             AND I.RELEASED_DATETIME >= @sdate 
             AND I.RELEASED_DATETIME < DATEADD(day, 1, @edate)
         GROUP BY 
             YEAR(I.RELEASED_DATETIME), MONTH(I.RELEASED_DATETIME), 
             DATENAME(MONTH, I.RELEASED_DATETIME)
      );

    -- Start of cursor
    DECLARE DTY CURSOR FOR
        SELECT RANGEPERIOD FROM @d

    OPEN DTY

    -- Fetch the first row
    FETCH NEXT FROM DTY INTO @cur

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @tot_enrls = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT I._ID) AS TOT_ENROLLS
                          FROM SVE_INTERACTION_SESSION_T AS I WITH (NOLOCK) 
                          INNER JOIN SVE_ENROLL_SESSION_T AS E WITH (NOLOCK) ON E.INTERACTION_SESSION_ID = I._ID 
                          INNER JOIN SVE_APPLICATIONS_T AS A WITH (NOLOCK) ON I.APPLICATION_ID = A._ID
                          WHERE
                              (I.DEVELOPER_OWNER_ID = @DEV_ID OR I.DEVELOPER_USER_ID = @DEV_ID) 
                              AND E.INSTANCE_ID = 0 
                              AND E.COMPLETION_STATUS = 'T' 
                              AND I.RELEASED_CODE = 'C' 
                              AND A.IS_DELETED = 0 
                              AND CONCAT( SUBSTRING( datename( month, I.RELEASED_DATETIME ), 1, 3 ), '-', YEAR( I.RELEASED_DATETIME ) ) = @cur
            );

        SET @tot_verfs = (
            SELECT
                COUNT( DISTINCT I._ID ) AS TOT_VERIFYS
            FROM
                SVE_INTERACTION_SESSION_T AS I WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN SVE_VERIFY_SESSION_T AS V WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON
                V.INTERACTION_SESSION_ID = I._ID INNER JOIN SVE_APPLICATIONS_T AS A WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON
                I.APPLICATION_ID = A._ID
            WHERE
                ( I.DEVELOPER_OWNER_ID = @DEV_ID OR I.DEVELOPER_USER_ID = @DEV_ID ) AND
                V.INSTANCE_ID = 0 AND
                V.COMPLETION_STATUS = 'S' AND
                I.RELEASED_CODE = 'C' AND
                A.IS_DELETED = 0 AND
                CONCAT( SUBSTRING( datename( month, I.RELEASED_DATETIME ), 1, 3 ), '-', YEAR( I.RELEASED_DATETIME ) ) = @cur
            );

     -- Updates the fields in the return table
        UPDATE
            @d
        SET
            TOTAL_ENROLLMENTS = @tot_enrls,
            TOTAL_VERIFICATIONS = @tot_verfs
        WHERE
            RANGEPERIOD = @cur

     -- Fetch the next row and repeat the above process
        FETCH NEXT FROM DTY INTO @cur
    END

 -- Updates the return table by setting all null values to 0 for better visuals
    UPDATE @d SET TOTAL_ENROLLMENTS = 0, TOTAL_VERIFICATIONS = 0 WHERE TOTAL_ENROLLMENTS IS NULL

    RETURN
END
```

It might be worth noting that I already do something similar for a range of days, and this works flawlessly.  The only difference is I use a calendar table for the day range function.  I know the secret sauce is in the temporary table that gets built from the calendar table, which i attempted to modify the month function to suit, but I'm at this point flustered

Here's the day function which works great

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SVE_GET_ENROL_VERIFY_COUNT_R]( @DEV_ID INT, @NUM_DAYS INT )
RETURNS @D TABLE
(
    RANGEDATE           DATE,
    TOTAL_ENROLLMENTS   INT,
    TOTAL_VERIFICATIONS INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @s DATE;          -- start date of range
    DECLARE @e DATE;          -- end date of range
    DECLARE @cur DATE;        -- stores the current record date the cursor points to
    DECLARE @tot_enrls INT;   -- stores the @cur date's enrollment count
    DECLARE @tot_verfs INT;   -- stores the @cur date's verification count

    SET @e = getdate();       -- stores today's date as the end date
    SET @s = DATEADD( dd, -( @NUM_DAYS-1 ), @e ); -- Subtract 1 from the incoming day and setup the accurate range of days

    INSERT INTO @d ( RANGEDATE )
    (
        SELECT
            RANGEDATE = c.d
        FROM
            Calendar AS c LEFT OUTER JOIN SVE_INTERACTION_SESSION_T as I WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON
            I.RELEASED_DATETIME >= @s AND I.RELEASED_DATETIME < = @e AND
            c.d = CONVERT( DATE, I.RELEASED_DATETIME )
        WHERE
            c.d >= @s AND c.d <= @e
        GROUP BY c.d
    );

 -- Start of cursor
    DECLARE DTY CURSOR FOR

    SELECT RANGEDATE FROM @d

    OPEN DTY

 -- Fetch the first row
    FETCH NEXT FROM DTY INTO @cur

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

    BEGIN
        -- Gets the developer's enrollment count for the current record's day
        SET @tot_enrls = (
            SELECT
                COUNT( DISTINCT I._ID ) AS TOT_ENROLLS
            FROM
                SVE_INTERACTION_SESSION_T AS I WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN SVE_ENROLL_SESSION_T AS E WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON
                E.INTERACTION_SESSION_ID = I._ID INNER JOIN SVE_APPLICATIONS_T AS A WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON
                I.APPLICATION_ID = A._ID
            WHERE
                ( I.DEVELOPER_OWNER_ID = @DEV_ID OR I.DEVELOPER_USER_ID = @DEV_ID ) AND
                E.INSTANCE_ID = 0 AND
                E.COMPLETION_STATUS = 'T' AND
                I.RELEASED_CODE = 'C' AND
                A.IS_DELETED = 0 AND
                I.RELEASED_DATETIME >= @cur AND 
                I.RELEASED_DATETIME < dateadd(day,1,@cur)
            );

        -- Gets the developer's verification count for the current record's day
        SET @tot_verfs = (
            SELECT
                COUNT( DISTINCT I._ID ) AS TOT_VERIFYS
            FROM
                SVE_INTERACTION_SESSION_T AS I WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN SVE_VERIFY_SESSION_T AS V WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON
                V.INTERACTION_SESSION_ID = I._ID INNER JOIN SVE_APPLICATIONS_T AS A WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON
                I.APPLICATION_ID = A._ID
            WHERE
                ( I.DEVELOPER_OWNER_ID = @DEV_ID OR I.DEVELOPER_USER_ID = @DEV_ID ) AND
                V.INSTANCE_ID = 0 AND
                V.COMPLETION_STATUS = 'S' AND
                I.RELEASED_CODE = 'C' AND
                A.IS_DELETED = 0 AND
                I.RELEASED_DATETIME >= @cur AND 
                I.RELEASED_DATETIME < dateadd(day,1,@cur)
            );

     -- Updates the fields in the return table
        UPDATE
            @d
        SET
            TOTAL_ENROLLMENTS = @tot_enrls,
            TOTAL_VERIFICATIONS = @tot_verfs
        WHERE
            RANGEDATE = @cur

     -- Fetch the next row and repeat the above process
        FETCH NEXT FROM DTY INTO @cur
    END

 -- Updates the return table by setting all null values to 0 for better visuals
    UPDATE @d SET TOTAL_ENROLLMENTS = 0, TOTAL_VERIFICATIONS = 0 WHERE TOTAL_ENROLLMENTS IS NULL

    RETURN
END
```

This is what my modification looks like for the month period to use the calendar table but its an epic fail, as it only returns one row.

```
INSERT INTO @d ( RANGEPERIOD )
(
    SELECT
        RANGEPERIOD = CONCAT( SUBSTRING( datename( month, c.d ), 1, 3 ), '-', YEAR( c.d ) )
    FROM
        Calendar AS c LEFT OUTER JOIN SVE_INTERACTION_SESSION_T as I WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON
        (YEAR(I.RELEASED_DATETIME) >= YEAR(@s) AND MONTH(I.RELEASED_DATETIME) >= MONTH(@s)) AND (YEAR(I.RELEASED_DATETIME) <= YEAR(@e) AND MONTH(I.RELEASED_DATETIME) <= MONTH(@e)) AND
        c.d = CONVERT( DATE, I.RELEASED_DATETIME )
    WHERE
        (YEAR(c.d) >= YEAR(@s) AND MONTH(c.d) >= MONTH(@s)) AND (YEAR(c.d) <= YEAR(@e) AND MONTH(c.d) <= MONTH(@e))
    GROUP BY c.d
);
```

Can someone point me in the right direction, or provide an assist?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you a specific point but I can give you some guidelines to resolve your problem.
I assume that you need the results in this format. (MMM-YYYY)

In your modification query, you can remove SVE_INTERACTION_SESSION_T table.

Because

1. You didn't select column from this table.
2. You were using LEFT JOIN then your result don't get the effect from your condition. The result still comes from whole table of calendar

   ```
   SELECT RANGEPERIOD = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(datename(MONTH, c.d), 1, 3), '-', YEAR(c.d))
   FROM Calendar AS c
   WHERE (YEAR(c.d) >= YEAR(@s) AND MONTH(c.d) >= MONTH(@s))
     AND (YEAR(c.d) <= YEAR(@e) AND MONTH(c.d) <= MONTH(@e))
   GROUP BY c.d
   ```

Comment: Hmm the query you proposed doesn't return any results for me.  Let me ask this, if you were presented with this request for data, how would you approach it, taking everything I've done out of consideration.  I have considered using two temporary tables, one to return all the days between the period, and then after tallying up the counts, run back through that table and group the results.  However this seems inefficient to me, and the last thing I want to do is slow down the query.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the fact that I didn't need the INTERACTION_SESSION Table in that query.  I figured out a solution for now where I get the dates from the calendar into a temp table, then group those dates in another table with the formatting i need. However, i'm curious to see how else this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in a solution to this see my code below.  It might not be the most efficient, but at the moment I cannot think of another solution.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SVE_GET_ENROL_VERIFY_COUNT_MONTH_R]( @DEV_ID INT, @NUM_MONTHS INT )
RETURNS @M TABLE
(
    RANGEPERIOD         VARCHAR(10),
    TOTAL_ENROLLMENTS   INT,
    TOTAL_VERIFICATIONS INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- We need to declare a temporary table to hold the days from the period
    DECLARE @D TABLE(
        RANGEDATE         DATETIME,
        TOTAL_ENROLLMENTS   INT,
        TOTAL_VERIFICATIONS INT
    )

    DECLARE @cur VARCHAR(12); -- stores the current record date the cursor points to
    DECLARE @sdate DATETIME;  -- start date of range
    DECLARE @edate DATETIME;  -- end date of range
    DECLARE @tot_enrls INT;   -- stores the @cur date's enrollment count
    DECLARE @tot_verfs INT;   -- stores the @cur date's verification count

    SELECT @sdate = DATEADD( MONTH, -( @NUM_MONTHS-1 ), GETDATE() )
    SELECT @edate = GETDATE(); 

    -- First fill the temp day table with dates from the calendar
    INSERT INTO @D ( RANGEDATE ) (
        SELECT
            RANGEDATE = CONVERT( DATE, c.d )
        FROM
            Calendar AS c
        WHERE
            c.d >= @sdate AND c.d <= @edate
        GROUP BY c.d
    )

    -- Next we fill our return table with our grouped by formatted dates 
    INSERT INTO @M ( RANGEPERIOD ) (
        SELECT
            RANGEPERIOD = CONCAT( SUBSTRING( datename( month, D.RANGEDATE ), 1, 3 ), '-', YEAR( D.RANGEDATE ) )
        FROM
            @D AS D
        GROUP BY year( D.RANGEDATE ), month( D.RANGEDATE ), datename( month, D.RANGEDATE )
    )

 -- Start of cursor
    DECLARE DTY CURSOR FOR

    SELECT RANGEPERIOD FROM @M

    OPEN DTY

 -- Fetch the first row
    FETCH NEXT FROM DTY INTO @cur

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

    BEGIN
        SET @tot_enrls = (
            SELECT
                COUNT( DISTINCT I._ID ) AS TOT_ENROLLS
            FROM
                SVE_INTERACTION_SESSION_T AS I WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN SVE_ENROLL_SESSION_T AS E WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON
                E.INTERACTION_SESSION_ID = I._ID INNER JOIN SVE_APPLICATIONS_T AS A WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON
                I.APPLICATION_ID = A._ID
            WHERE
                ( I.DEVELOPER_OWNER_ID = @DEV_ID OR I.DEVELOPER_USER_ID = @DEV_ID ) AND
                E.INSTANCE_ID = 0 AND
                E.COMPLETION_STATUS = 'T' AND
                I.RELEASED_CODE = 'C' AND
                A.IS_DELETED = 0 AND
                CONCAT( SUBSTRING( datename( month, I.RELEASED_DATETIME ), 1, 3 ), '-', YEAR( I.RELEASED_DATETIME ) ) = @cur
            );

        SET @tot_verfs = (
            SELECT
                COUNT( DISTINCT I._ID ) AS TOT_VERIFYS
            FROM
                SVE_INTERACTION_SESSION_T AS I WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN SVE_VERIFY_SESSION_T AS V WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON
                V.INTERACTION_SESSION_ID = I._ID INNER JOIN SVE_APPLICATIONS_T AS A WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON
                I.APPLICATION_ID = A._ID
            WHERE
                ( I.DEVELOPER_OWNER_ID = @DEV_ID OR I.DEVELOPER_USER_ID = @DEV_ID ) AND
                V.INSTANCE_ID = 0 AND
                V.COMPLETION_STATUS = 'S' AND
                I.RELEASED_CODE = 'C' AND
                A.IS_DELETED = 0 AND
                CONCAT( SUBSTRING( datename( month, I.RELEASED_DATETIME ), 1, 3 ), '-', YEAR( I.RELEASED_DATETIME ) ) = @cur
            );

     -- Updates the fields in the return table
        UPDATE
            @M
        SET
            TOTAL_ENROLLMENTS = @tot_enrls,
            TOTAL_VERIFICATIONS = @tot_verfs
        WHERE
            RANGEPERIOD = @cur

     -- Fetch the next row and repeat the above process
        FETCH NEXT FROM DTY INTO @cur
    END

 -- Updates the return table by setting all null values to 0 for better visuals
    UPDATE @M SET TOTAL_ENROLLMENTS = 0, TOTAL_VERIFICATIONS = 0 WHERE TOTAL_ENROLLMENTS IS NULL

    RETURN
END
```